# What kind of sorcery is Maven doing to run this project, when I can't?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, dll

I have a maven project with some library dependencies (.dll) (which I put in a "lib" folder). I can run the project without problems in Netbeans, but when I try to run the built .jar outside of Netbeans, I get the following error on loading the library:

`Can't load this .dll (machine code=0xbd) on a AMD 64-bit platform`

I only have **one** instance of Java installed on my computer, it should be the same JVM that Netbeans/Maven uses to run the project. So I can't understand how Netbeans/Maven is able to run this application on a different platform than me? I've tried looking at the command Netbeans executes (from the output) to run the project and I think it's this:

```
cd C:\Users\Birger\Workspace\myproject; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_91" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.1\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dexec.args=\"-Djava.library.path=lib\\ -classpath %classpath com.mysite.myproject.Main\" -Dexec.executable=\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_91\\bin\\java.exe\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.1\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec\""
```

I tried these two commands

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\bin\java.exe" -Djava.library.path=lib\ -jar myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe" -Djava.library.path=lib\ -jar myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I added `System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));` to get my application to print out the cpu architecture. It prints `64` in both occasions.

Tried looking into the "mvn.bat" file in `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.1\java\maven\bin\mvn.bat` but I couldn't find any clues as to what Maven is doing to run my application.

Can somebody help me on this one?

Birger

**EDIT**

Here's the complete source code of my test project. My project's `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mysite</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo</id>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/temp-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jni4net</groupId>
            <artifactId>jni4net.j</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/lib
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.mysite.myproject.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>          
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>lib</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>              
                        </configuration>            
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My project's class

```
package com.mysite.myproject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import net.sf.jni4net.Bridge;

public class Main {

    static {
        String libDir = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
        System.loadLibrary("jni4net.n-0.8.8.0");

        if (System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model").equals("64")) {
            System.loadLibrary("jni4net.n.w64.v20-0.8.8.0");
            System.loadLibrary("jni4net.n.w64.v40-0.8.8.0");
        } else {
            System.loadLibrary("jni4net.n.w32.v20-0.8.8.0");
            System.loadLibrary("jni4net.n.w32.v40-0.8.8.0");
        }

        try {
            Bridge.init(new File(libDir));
            System.out.println("Initialized!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Netbeans output when running the project (added `--debug` option for verbose output):

```
cd C:\Users\Birger\Workspace\myproject; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_91" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.1\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dexec.args=\"-Djava.library.path=lib\\ -classpath %classpath com.mysite.myproject.Main\" -Dexec.executable=\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_91\\bin\\java.exe\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.1\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 --debug org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec\""
Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 14:51:28+0100)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.1\java\maven
Java version: 1.8.0_91, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
Populating class realm maven.ext
  Included C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.1\java\maven-nblib\netbeans-eventspy.jar
Error stacktraces are turned on.
Reading global settings from C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.1\java\maven\conf\settings.xml
Reading user settings from C:\Users\Birger\.m2\settings.xml
Using local repository at C:\Users\Birger\.m2\repository
Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for C:\Users\Birger\.m2\repository
Scanning for projects...
Extension realms for project com.mysite:myproject:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: (none)
Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[maven.ext, parent: ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
=== REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
Project: com.mysite:myproject:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
Tasks:   [org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec]
Style:   Regular
=======================================================================

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building myproject 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
=== PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
Project:       com.mysite:myproject:1.0-SNAPSHOT
Dependencies (collect): []
Dependencies (resolve): [test]
Repositories (dependencies): [libs-release (http://artifactory.osc.no:8081/artifactory/libs-release/, releases), repo (file://C:\Users\Birger\Workspace\myproject/temp-repo, releases+snapshots), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)]
Repositories (plugins)     : [libs-release (http://artifactory.osc.no:8081/artifactory/libs-release/, releases), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Goal:          org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli)
Style:         Regular
Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <basedir default-value="${basedir}"/>
  <classpathScope default-value="runtime">${exec.classpathScope}</classpathScope>
  <commandlineArgs>${exec.args}</commandlineArgs>
  <executable>${exec.executable}</executable>
  <longClasspath default-value="false">${exec.longClasspath}</longClasspath>
  <outputFile>${exec.outputFile}</outputFile>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
  <session default-value="${session}"/>
  <skip default-value="false">${skip}</skip>
  <sourceRoot>${sourceRoot}</sourceRoot>
  <testSourceRoot>${testSourceRoot}</testSourceRoot>
  <workingDirectory>${exec.workingdir}</workingDirectory>
</configuration>
=======================================================================
com.mysite:myproject:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
   jni4net:jni4net.j:jar:0.8.8.0:compile

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ myproject ---
Created new class realm maven.api
Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
  Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.version < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.* < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.artifact < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.* < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.project < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.repository < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.impl < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.collection < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.metadata < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.spi < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.graph < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.installation < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.transfer < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.deployment < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.model < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < maven.ext
  Imported: org.sonatype.aether.resolution < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < maven.ext
  Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < maven.ext
  Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < maven.ext
Populating class realm maven.api
org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.2.1:
   org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:1.0:compile
   org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6:compile
   org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6:compile
   org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6:compile
   org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6:compile
   org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6:compile
      org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
         org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-7:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6:compile
      commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6:compile
      org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6:compile
      classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1:compile
   org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5:compile
   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9:compile
      junit:junit:jar:3.8.2:test (scope managed from compile) (version managed from 3.8.1)
   org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.1:compile
Created new class realm plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1
Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1
  Imported:  < maven.api
Populating class realm plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1
  Included: org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.2.1
  Included: org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6
  Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-7
  Included: commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0
  Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4
  Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5
  Included: org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.1
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:1.0
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6
  Excluded: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9
  Excluded: junit:junit:jar:3.8.2
Configuring mojo org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05]
Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec' with basic configurator -->
  (f) basedir = C:\Users\Birger\Workspace\myproject
  (f) classpathScope = runtime
  (f) commandlineArgs = -Djava.library.path=lib\ -classpath %classpath com.mysite.myproject.Main
  (f) executable = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe
  (f) longClasspath = false
  (f) project = MavenProject: com.mysite:myproject:1.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\Birger\Workspace\myproject\pom.xml
  (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@2ef14fe
  (f) skip = false
-- end configuration --
Collected project artifacts [jni4net:jni4net.j:jar:0.8.8.0:compile]
Collected project classpath [C:\Users\Birger\Workspace\myproject\target\classes]
dealing with jni4net:jni4net.j:jar:0.8.8.0:compile
Toolchains are ignored, 'executable' parameter is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe
Executing command line: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe -Djava.library.path=lib\ -classpath C:\Users\Birger\Workspace\myproject\target\classes;C:\Users\Birger\.m2\repository\jni4net\jni4net.j\0.8.8.0\jni4net.j-0.8.8.0.jar com.mysite.myproject.Main
Initialized!
Hello world!
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.360s
Finished at: Fri Jul 08 09:26:48 CEST 2016
Final Memory: 5M/245M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Command-line output when trying to run my built .jar

```
C:\Users\Birger\Workspace\myproject\target>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe" -Djava.library.path=lib\ -jar myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Birger\Workspace\myproject\target\lib\jni4net.n-0.8.8.0.dll: Can't load this .dll (machine code=0xbd) on a AMD 64-bit platform
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at com.mysite.myproject.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:11)
```

**EDIT2:**

For anyone looking to reproduce this error, jni4net can be found [here](http://jni4net.com/). I installed the .jar with this windows batch file:

```
set project_dir=YOURPROJECTDIRECTORYHERE
set proxygen_dir=YOURPROXYGENINSTALLATIONDIRECTORYHERE
set temp_repo_dir=%project_dir%\temp-repo
call mvn install:install-file -DlocalRepositoryPath=%temp_repo_dir% -DcreateChecksum=true -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=%proxygen_dir%\lib\jni4net.j-0.8.8.0.jar -DgroupId=jni4net -DartifactId=jni4net.j -Dversion=0.8.8.0
```

**EDIT3:**

I installed 32-bit JVM, and tried running the application with the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe" -Djava.library.path=lib\ -jar myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Now I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Birger\Workspace\myproject\target\lib\jni4net.n.w32.v20-0.8.8.0.dll: Can't load this .dll (machine code=0xbd) on a IA 32-bit platform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysite.myproject.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:19)
```

I'm getting quite desperate here (and a little frustrated with Java tbh)

**EDIT4:**

Tried these commands, also not working:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java" -Djava.library.path=lib\ -classpath C:\Users\Birger\Workspace\myproject\target\classes;C:\Users\Birger\.m2\repositor‌​y\jni4net\jni4net.j\0.8.8.0\jni4net.j-0.8.8.0.jar com.mysite.myproject.Main
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java" -Djava.library.path=lib\ -classpath classes;C:\Users\Birger\.m2\repositor‌​y\jni4net\jni4net.j\0.8.8.0\jni4net.j-0.8.8.0.jar com.mysite.myproject.Main
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java" -Djava.library.path=lib\ -classpath classes com.mysite.myproject.Main
```

Comment: Make a tiny example that reproduces the problem that others can see.

Comment: Try running Maven with the `--debug` option, that should give you more detailed information about what Maven is doing exactly.

Comment: The run does not seem to find a 64bits dll but instead is given a 32bits one, maybe NetBeans ran it under 32 bits. `System.getProperties().list(System.out);` would show that info. Picking "C:/Program Files (x86)/java/..." might help.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, guys. See my question's update for the complete source code of myproject, and run output.

Comment: Added `System.getProperties().list(System.out);`to the source code, to compare when running Netbeans/Maven and from command-line. The output is actually identical.

Comment: I noticed when I installed netbeans it installed both a 32 and a 64 bit version of the exe in the bin directory under program files\netbeans.  Which version are you running when it works?  My guess is you're running the 32 bit version and if you try the same thing with the 64 bit version it will fail similar to the cmd line attempt.  I suspect NB comes with a bundled JVM it uses if you don't have a suitable version on your machine.

Comment: The "bin" directory has three files: `netbeans.exe`, `netbeans64.exe` and `netbeans`. I tried removing the `netbeans.exe` and `netbeans` files, restarted the IDE. The project still runs from Netbeans.

Comment: hmmm silly though but i have to ask , when maven finishes the build , are you sure it updates properly the /target directory with the latest `myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` ?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Deleted the entire `target` directory, before compiling and tried running the application.

Comment: In the first edit, in the end of debug Netbeans / Maven output one could see following line: `Executing command line: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe -Djava.library.path=lib\ -classpath C:\Users\Birger\Workspace\myproject\target\classes;C:\Users\Birger\.m2\repository\jni4net\jni4net.j\0.8.8.0\jni4net.j-0.8.8.0.jar com.mysite.myproject.Main`. Comparing this with your command-line I could see that you don't include `-classpath` and only add executable jar using `-jar myproject.jar`. I think this could be the issue

Comment: I also tried running the application without the .jar and providing the classpath with the `-classpath` argument and running the main class. It yields the same error.

Comment: It appears you have two versions(32/64) of dll files and get them mixed together.
Are you sure you point to correct maven config `\maven\conf\settings.xml` and repository within netbeans and outside ?

Comment: @Birger could you please provide command with `-classpath` that you used to run it?

Comment: @Yura sure, see **EDIT4**

Comment: Are you sure that `jni4net.n.w32.v20-0.8.8.0.dll` file is not corrupted? Try to download it again (or maybe a different version) and copy-paste it to correct location.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I faced this problem long time ago.

just remove the `<filtering>true</filtering>` ,this get the files corrupted while copying. (Bug !!???).

I was able to reproduce your issue. this will resolve your problem also

hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this resolves the error. Thanks. What in the world is "filtering" and why is it destroying the .dll's?

Comment: filtering allow you to use variables for your resources. hier explained https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Comment: More specifically, resource filtering attempts to perform variable substitution on resources handled by the plugin.; i.e. it finds and replaces things that look like `"${some.name}"` in the resource.  If you do this on a non-text resource, you are liable to corrupt it.  It is not a bug ... it is a feature.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the .dll's copied during compile are unusable by my application. To get it working, I have to load the original library files (not the copied ones). Netbeans was doing excactly this, thus my application ran fine from Netbeans but not when trying to use the compiled (and copied) files.

**FIX**: In my `pom.xml`, resource filtering is set to `true`. I set it to `false` (or remove the entry), and now my application can be launched from outside netbeans. Here's my new `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mysite</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo</id>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/temp-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jni4net</groupId>
            <artifactId>jni4net.j</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/lib
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.mysite.myproject.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>          
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>lib</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>            
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: then the correct way should be excluding the jni's instead of turning off filtering.
Filtering is a way to "replace" "variable" at resource file with value from the pom / maven. Usefull for multiple configuration. I suspect in the library file there are text that have variable format, something `${likethis}`

Comment: I see. So it is replacing recognized variable names with values? I don't think I would put anything in the `lib` folder which would be a suitable subject to this feature. But I can see how it would be better to enable filtering and excluding the .dll's for some other cases (resource folders).